# How to create QTcpServer on a QThread and then stop it from the main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have provided my entire code below. Please excuse the design as I am new to Qt and this is a quick and dirty example.

What I want to do is create a QThread that manages a QTcpServer listener. I want it to be able to close listener when stopped and then reopen it when started again. Please ignore the fact that the listener may be getting leaked right now, I will tackle that issue later.

I believe the problem is that when Stop is called it invokes the m_listener->close() method on a different thread (invoked from the main thread) than the thread it was created on (it was created on the TcpServerThread). So the questions is, how to I fix it? Or how to I redesign it so I avoid this issue?

This isn't the full design, I have made a toy example that mimicks the real thing.

tcpserverthread.h

```
#ifndef TCPSERVERTHREAD_H
#define TCPSERVERTHREAD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class QTcpServer;

class TcpServerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TcpServerThread();

    void run();

    void Start();
    void Stop();
public slots:
    void newConnection();

private:

    QTcpServer* m_pListener;
};

#endif // TCPSERVERTHREAD_H
```

tcpserverthread.cpp

```
#include "tcpserverthread.h"
#include "tcpserver.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QCoreApplication>

TcpServerThread::TcpServerThread()
{

}

void TcpServerThread::run()
{
    std::cout << "thread started ..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "listener starting ..." << std::endl;
    m_pListener = new QTcpServer();
    connect(m_pListener, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnection()));
    if(!m_pListener->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234))
    {
        std::cout << "listener could NOT START - " << m_pListener->errorString().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "listener SUCCESSFULLY STARTED" << std::endl;
    }

//    std::cout << "thread running..." << std::endl;
//    m_pListener = new TcpServer();
//    m_pListener->Start();

    exec();
}

void TcpServerThread::newConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "in new conn ... ";
    //std::cout << "in new conn.." << std::endl;
    QTcpSocket *soc = m_pListener->nextPendingConnection();
    soc->write("hello client");
}

void TcpServerThread::Start()
{
    start();
}

void TcpServerThread::Stop()
{
    std::cout << "TcpServer Stopping . . . " << std::endl;
    //this close is the line that causes the problem... 
    m_pListener->close();
    this->quit();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include "tcpserver.h"

#include "tcpserverthread.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    TcpServerThread *t = new TcpServerThread();
    t->Start();
    t->Stop();

    return a.exec();
}
```

If you comment out the call to t->Stop in main you can then run it and use telnet (or putty) to connect to it @ 127.0.0.1:1234.

I want to make it so it can be stopped and then started again and connections will work.

Comment: I see you made a `Start` function that calls the `start` function.. I also like to live dangerously :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you are going about using QThread the wrong way here. If you are going to inherit from QThread then this should be because you want to extend the functionality of threading, which is not what you want.

QThread is a class used to control a thread and for you, should not be a part of your class. Instead you should design your class `TcpServer` (not `TcpServerThread`) as you have but remove the thread elements. Then make run(), start() and stop() slots. Also you need to inherit from QObject to use signals and slots. Something like this:

```
class TcpServer: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT // don't forget this
    :
    :
}
```

Then in main you can create your thread and your class, and then move your class into the thread:

```
TcpServer *pTcpServer = new TcpServer();
QThread *pThread = new QThread;
pTcpServer->moveToThread(pThread);
// Connect thread start to your run() function
connect(pThread, &QThread::started, pTcpServer, &TcpServer::run, Qt::QueuedConnection);
// Now run your thread, when it starts your run() slot will be called
thread->start();
```

As to calling your start/stop - what triggers a start/stop? I assume some other object will start/stop the server, or some event? In any case you will connect them in the same way:

```
connect(pSomeClass, &SomeClass::startTcpServer, pTcpServer, &TcpServer::start, Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(pSomeClass, &SomeClass::stopTcpServer, pTcpServer, &TcpServer::stop, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

**note**

I think the reason you are seeing some objects created in main thread is because you are calling functions directly into your class (`start()` / `stop()`). Doing this across the thread "boundary" is not safe since any actions taken (or objects allocated) would be done within the calling thread (main thread). You need to use the slot / signal mechanism (or some other thread-safe mechanism).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid taking the QTcpServer object out of the QThread class simply because I wanted to do as minor of a change as possible. However, it does not appear that I will be able to avoid that because I have tried it a blue million different ways and cannot get anything to work. I would be curious if you know a way to make it work using a design like the code I posted. 

Either way, I did get things working in a sample app using the design you give. So THANK  YOU, code_fodder. I will just go ahead and redesign the real thing this way because I do not see a way to avoid it. Thoughts?

Comment: I believe you can get it working with the code you posted. However you need to change a few things: Firstly and perhaps most importantly, do not call functions directly on your class other then `t->start();`. Once you call t->start() then `run()` will be called. Personally I would not change `run()` - i.e. overload it as you have, I would take your code out and move it into a slot called `startup()` or something and also make your `Stop()` function a slot. Now from here on in you use slots / signals to communicate to your thread object.

Comment: In your code by calling `t->Stop()` directly means you are running the Stop() code in the calling thread and not in the server thread. This is not thread safe and is why you get your issue (or one reason at least). You must never do that, so replace any such things with slot/signals.

Comment: @cchampion yes by all means do that : )  .. just one question, do you really mean to stop it almost as soon as you start it? - in your main() you have start() and stop() right after each other - surely you want some event to occur which triggers you to stop?, it could be a timer, user input, when you terminate the program..etc... think about how/when you really want to stop it.

Comment: Right, keep in mind this is just sample code to learn how to start, stop and then start the server again across threads. The real code does much more which I cannot get into. I should be able to use this pattern and everything work nicely no matter what thread close is called from.

Still working on it but I will post it before this evening. Kind of working on it intermittently because family is around.

Comment: In my example I may even put in a UI thread and have it start stop it. Depends on time (wife wants to watch a movie lol).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115043/discussion-between-cchampion-and-code-fodder).